# factorial recursion and iteration in python

Tags: python, recursion

please help me understand where i went wrong:

this is the question:Create both a recursive function called recursive_factorial and iterative function called iterative_factorial that does the following

```
Accepts as parameter an Integer n
Computes the factorial of n
Returns the factorial of n
```

this is the test i am using for the question:

```
import unittest

class RecursiveTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_recursive_factorial_one(self):
    result = recursive_factorial(4)
    self.assertEqual(result, 24, msg="Inaccurate value")

  def test_recursive_factorial_two(self):
    result = recursive_factorial(0)
    self.assertEqual(result, 1, msg="Inaccurate value")

  def test_iterative_factorial_one(self):
    result = iterative_factorial(5)
    self.assertEqual(result, 120, msg="Inaccurate value")

  def test_iterative_factorial_two(self):
    result = iterative_factorial(0)
    self.assertEqual(result, 1, msg="Inaccurate value")
```

this is the code i have written:

```
def recursive_factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * recursive_factorial(n-1)
def iterative_factorial(n):
    x = 1
    li = list(range(1, n + 1))
    for each in li:
        x = x * each
```

this is the error i am getting:

1 .  test_iterative_factorial_one

```
Failure in line 21, in test_iterative_factorial_one self.assertEqual(result, 120, msg="Inaccurate value") AssertionError: Inaccurate value
```

2 .  test_iterative_factorial_two

```
Failure in line 25, in test_iterative_factorial_two self.assertEqual(result, 1, msg="Inaccurate value") AssertionError: Inaccurate value
```

please help me understand where i went wrong.

Comment: `iterative_factorial(n):` has no `return`

Comment: Can you add some debug to print the result of `recursive_factorial(0)`.  The code looks correct.

Answer (score 5):

You're forgetting to `return x` from `iterative_factorial()`, so the function is [implicitly returning `None`](https://mellowd.co.uk/ccie/?p=5177).

As an aside, you can iterate of the result of `range()` directly:

```
for each in range(1, n + 1):
   ...
```

Finally, this might be a good opportunity to learn about Python's [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function.

```
import operator

def another_iterative_factorial(n):
   return reduce(operator.mul, range(1, n + 1))
```

Comment: and if you are using python3 reduce was moved to the functools module. Also, good chance to learn about [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) function as you can write `reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,range(1,n+1))`

Answer (score 1):

`iterative_factorial` needs to end with

```
    return x
```

Also, `iterative_factorial` doesn't need `li`.  Better to just write:

```
    for each in range(1,n+1):
```

Comment: `test_recurisve_factorial_two` tests 0!, not 2!

Comment: D'oh!  In that case I don't understand.

Comment: @Davismuriungi - make sure to accept NPE's answer.  It was written first; it didn't start out with errors; and it includes `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def recursive_factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * recursive_factorial(n-1)


def iterative_factorial(n):        
    x = 1
    li = list(range(2, n+1))
    for each in li:
        x = x*each
        yield x
```

Comment: You need to fix the indentation of the `return x` sentence in `iterative_factorial`.

Comment: You could simplify `iterative_factorial` by writing `for each in range(2, n + 1):`